# Calling multiple functions in single express route call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, cheerio

I created a web scraping function with cheerio.js that I want to get called when the user opens the home page. I got it to work with one function, but I actually have 3 scraping functions that all do slightly different things. How do I add those functions in my route call to the home page along with the first function call? (basically i want all the data to be scraped upon the user opening the home page)

I'm also not very familiar with async/await or promises and got this code to work by following examples online, so if something is wrong there please let me know!

express route call that works (`index.js`):

```js
const getSUPResults = require("./routes/SUPstores");
app.use(getSUPResults);

app.get("/", async function(req, res, next){
  const result = await getSUPResults();
  res.render("index", result);
});
```

scraper function (`"./routes/SUPstores"`)

```js
const express = require("express");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const { default: Axios } = require("axios");

const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await Axios.get("http://example.com");
    return cheerio.load(result.data);
};

const getSUPResults = async () => {
    const $ = await fetchData();
    const SUPStoreInfo = [];

        $('.row > tbody > tr:contains("SUP")').each(function(i, element){
            const SUPResult = {
                "environment" : $(this).children().text(),
                "store" : $(this).children().next().text(),
                "version" : $(this).children().next().next().text()
            };
            SUPStoreInfo.push(SUPResult);
        });
        return SUPStoreInfo;
}

module.exports = getSUPResults;
```

I tried to do something like this, but it only seemed to call the first function (getSUPResults), and ignored the rest. Is there something similar to this I could try?

```js
const getSUPResults = require("./routes/SUPstores");
const getQAResults = require("./routes/QAstores");
const getDEVResults = require("./routesDEVstores");

app.use(getSUPResults);
app.use(getQAResults);
app.use(getDEVResults);

app.get("/", async function(req, res, next){
  const SUP = await getSUPResults();
  const QA = await getQAResults();
  const DEV = await getDEVResults();
  const result = [SUP, QA, DEV];
  res.render("index", result);
});
```

Comment: a [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) fetches them concurrently. since you are doing this server-side you should be able to cache the result to deliver fastest page loads.

Comment: What Ronnie said, and also those app.use lines means you're using those functions as middlewares which I don't think you want and will mess things up.